# Dagger2 Maven Eclipse Integration

Tags: eclipse, maven, dagger, dagger-2, annotation-processing

I try to migrate a bigger maven project from guice to dagger2. The annotation processing is integrated using the m2e-apt plugin. The code generation works fine if all injected dependencies can be provided.

If a dependency can not be provided I just get an general compile issue in eclipse on the component interface. If I compile using maven on the terminal I get a detailed error pointing to the class, that can not be provided.

Is there any trick to show this error of the annotation processor in eclipse? Without such an error I have no chance to find the class which can not be provided.

Comment: This should not happen.  Please show how does it look after a full rebuild?